# Using awk to calculate average of grades

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, command

I have a file like this:

```
id1 name1 grade1 grade2 grade3....gradeN
id2 name2 grade1 grade2 grade3....gradeN
etc
```

and I want to print the id, name and average of grades of each row using awk.
any idea?
the output should be like:

```
id1 name1 avg_of_grades
id2 name2 avg_of_grades
```

Comment: Post some sample input and expected output instead of or in addition to the information about the general layout of the files. i.e. post something we could run a script on and compare the output to for testing.

Answer (score 6):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{sum=0;for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) sum+=$i; print $1, $2, (NF>2?sum/(NF-2):0)}' file
```

Iterate from third column to end of line and capture the total in a variable called `sum`. Once that is done, just print column 1, 2 and the average. Since `sum` will contain rolling total, we set it to `0` at the start of our script to initialize it for each line.

Note for average, I used `NF` variable which contains the total number of columns for each line. We subtract 2 to get correct total (we start capture from third column).

Also, I have added a check for division by zero in cases you just have two columns.

Comment: +1 for making sense from this question without any data shown

Comment: How can you do the exact same thing except for: you do not know how many middle names a person has? I am thinking REGEX (regular expressions)> The way I see it you'd have to: not start from the 3rd field, but from the field that only has digits, because therefore each field after that would onlny have digits. Don't know how to implement it, though.